# Why doesn't this closure work?

Tags: ruby

In the example below, I would have thought that `close_over_me` would be available to the returned object through a closure.

But clearly that is not the case.

Why not?

Also, what options are available for making the code work as expected (that is, returning the value 1 rather than an error)?

```
def test_closure(close_over_me: 1)
  Object.new.tap do |x|
    def x.captured_var
      close_over_me
    end
  end
end

o = test_closure
o.captured_var # NameError: undefined local variable or method `close_over_me' for #<Object:0x007fb46b41a718>
```

Comment: It is not best practice to define a method within another method definition.

Comment: @HunterStevens, That has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: I meant to say that it may be best to create 2 distinct methods, as to maybe avoid the issue you are having. But it was then too late for me to edit my comment. The answers below work around the double definition, though :-)

Comment: @HunterStevens, I wasn't asking how to do it some other way that works around the problem.  That's obviously trivial.  The point of the question was to *understand*, not to *avoid* understanding by doing the "normal" thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that the `def` keyword defines a new scope.

To work around this, you can use `Object#define_singleton_method` instead:

```
def test_closure(close_over_me: 1)
  Object.new.tap do |x|
    x.define_singleton_method(:captured_var) do
      close_over_me
    end
  end
end

o = test_closure
o.captured_var # => 1
```

Answer (score 3):

It's so-called "scope gate". Keywords `def`/`class`/`module` push all local variables out of scope.

You'll have to come up with a way to do your patching without those.